# How to link Flutter with NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, flutter, http, rest

I have been working on an app to link my app with a custom designed backend written in Node  following the practices of REST API. But I dont know how to link them both.
Would be really helpful if someone could help me out in that

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a Model.
For model class, you can follow this documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json
. Then create a Client Service to get the response from the database. For example like this.

```
  Future<List<Doctor>> getDoctors() async {
    final response = await http.get(baseUrl, headers: _header);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      return List<Doctor>.from(data['data'].map((item) => Doctor.fromJson(item)));
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed");
    }
  }
```

Then create a FutureBuilder to get the data from the Client Service.

```
        FutureBuilder<List<Doctor>>(
              future: Client().getData, //It is better if you call the client service in the initState
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(snapshot);
                    return Center(
                      child: Text("Error"),
                    );
                  }
                  else if (snapshot.hasData){
                    print(snapshot.data)
                  }
                  else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Container(),
                    );
                }
              },
            )
```